# how to style one object inside a component tag angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

I want to add a style just the [text] inside this component tag

```
<i *ngIf="m.length<=0" >
    <ul>
      <angular_component
        [text]= "main" 
        [id]="sub"
        (deleteIconClicked)="sub_main"
      ></ngular_component>
    </ul>
```

anyone can help on how to do that
I want to add a style as such

```
<i *ngIf="m.length<=0" >
    <ul>
      <angular_component
<span class="bold">
        [text]= "main" </span>
        [id]="sub"
        (deleteIconClicked)="sub_main"
      ></ngular_component>
    </ul>
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do. Can you provide more detail? For instance what you've tried to do already, what didn't work. What you have now, and what you expect the outcome to be. To provide a stackblitz is always convenient

Comment: I want to add a style class to just [text]="main"

Comment: please explain in detail as it is still not clear where do you want to apply class

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you want to add style for an element inside angular_component. for this purpose you can use ng-deep pseudo-class.  [read more about component styling in angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)